Duty cycle calculation of phase-shift dc-dc converter
EXPLANATION
I shared the general waveform of this converter for MOSFETs and waveform formed in the transformer in picture 1.
The following information regarding duty cycle are available in the Phase-Shifted Full-Bridge converter document published by Texas Instruments.
It says the duty cycle is calculated as 0.66 in page 39. I think this is the duty cycle for the waveform of the transformer which is called Vsw in picture 1.
It also has the duty cycle calculation which is given below in picture 2, page 23.
Fsw is defined as


FSW refers to the switching frequency applied to the power transformer. The output inductor experiences a switching frequency which is 2 x FSW


in page 39 so I can understand that Fsw is for the MOSFETs (such as QA, QB, QC, QD).  Fsw is given as 100kHz in the document.
If I use the information in the equation given in picture 2, results appears as below ;
The document says TMIN is defined as


The TMIN pulse is measured from the rising edge of OUTA to the falling edge of OUTD ''


so TMIN corresponds to the Vsw pulse given in picture 1.
TMIN = 0.66 / ( 100kHz x 10^-4 ) = 0.00066s.
0.00066s means 660000 ns so this value is not in the range of the table given in picture 3. The table also from the document.
If the Fsw for the MOSFETs is 100kHz that means it makes 200kHz for the transformer (Vsw in picture 1) and output inductor as well.
Considering this 200kHz, When I want to verify it in the classical way ; 1/200kHz = 0.000005s , so since duty is 0.66 that means the pulse width is 0.000005 x 0.66 = 0.0000033s. This values is also not matching with the 0.00066s.
QUESTIONS
Why is the calculated TMIN 0.00066s is not within the table's limits?
Considering the 200kHz, 0.0000033s is not matching with the 0.00066s, why?
Picture 1. Waveforms of Mosfets and transformer

Source: https://digibuo.uniovi.es/dspace/bitstream/handle/10651/52653/TFM_AsselZhaksylyk.pdf?sequence=6
Picture 2. Dutcy cycle calculation given in the document

Source: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf
Picture 3. TMIN table given in the document

Source: https://www.lcsc.com/datasheet/lcsc_datasheet_Texas-Instruments-TI-UCC28950PWR_C91312.pdf

I've rolled back your question to how it was when I answered it. The act of changing your question following my answer to match what my answer said is unwise to say the least. I think you know this should not be done.

If it helps, I gave this answer a while ago.

@Mhan Do not edit your question in a way that invalidates an existing answer. If you have a new question based on an answer then post a new one -- questions are free here.

From the graph in the document, TMIN is about 60 ns (visual inspection) and, at a switching frequency of 200 kHz, DMIN will be: -
$$60\times 200\times 10^{-4} = 1.2\text{%}$$
This seems a wholly reasonable number but, in your reverse calculation you seem to be ignoring the units advice written below the formula you posted: -


Okay considering units, TMIN= 66/(100kHz x 10^-4) = 660ns , so that means 1 complete pulse of Vsw is 1000ns.  1/1000ns =1.000.000 Hz  , it was supposed to be 200kHz but it is not again.  (dont forget Fsw=100kHz is for mosfets and 200kHz is for Vsw which is transformer side ) @Andy aka
